# Github Local repository not updating the list of branches in Remote Repository

Tags: git

I'm currently new to git and github, whenever I create new branches or delete a branch, it seems like it does not reflect the changes on my local repository.

I tried already

- `git pull origin master`
- `git fetch all`

[!here is a picture when i use git branch and -r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isKFa.png)

Comment: When you delete branches in a remote, you need to use `git fetch --prune` for your local to delete the local references of those deleted remote branches

Comment: Note that GitHub is not really relevant here, other than to the extent that it's a hosting site for Git repositories. You could use GitLab or Bitbucket and have exactly the same situation. Keep in mind that Git is a Distributed Version Control System (DVCS), while Bitbucket and company are *hosting sites* that allow you to *store* a repository "in the cloud". You'll see this information in the pop-up text for each of the relevant tags.